# Store letter of windows drive

Tags: cmd

How can I access windows drive(main drive) via command line?
usually c drive is main but in different computer maybe it's not.
now I want store letter of windows drive(C or D or...) into a variable.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the system drive letter is stored in `%SystemDrive%`.

you can check it (and other system variables) simply executing `SET` without arguments on a command shell

Comment: Similarly the `%homedrive%` variable will usually report the same as the `%systemdrive%` variable, but is meant to show where the user profile is kept.